# Is there a way to distinguish answers from questions while reviewing edits?

Tags: discussion, review

I was reviewing an edit in the suggested edits review queue, I improved the edit and then just went to see the question so I try to see if I can answer it.

To my surprise it wasn't a question, it was a question added as an answer. So it should have been flagged as "Not an answer" in the first place, and didn't need an edit.

So my question is, is there a way to distinguish questions from answers in the [Suggested Edits](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits) review queue, am I not seeing something here? Or is it fine to approve them and then flag them?

In my opinion, it is just bumping the question to the homepage for no reason.

[This is the example edit I'm talking about.](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/219828)

<sup>**Note: I did flag it as not an answer.**</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some screenshots of edits against questions and answers so you can see for yourself.

### edit against a question

[image]

### edit against an answer

[image]

Down at the bottom next to the avatars it states "asked" or "answered".

Comment: I'm so blind...

Comment: Well, you saw it at least.

Comment: Can you provide links to your review items so I can check if my theory holds true for other SE sites?

Answer (score 2):

This is a *very* subtle (and hard to remember) difference, but the heading for an answer is **bolded** and slightly lighter [in colour] than the heading for a question

> #### [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123553/how-to-install-google-appengine)
>
> [image]

> #### [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123553/how-to-install-google-appengine/368827#368827)
>
> [image]

For easier comparison, I've placed them side by side below:

> [image] <sup>(question)</sup>  
> [image] <sup>(answer)</sup>

---

The same difference is also in your [Review History tab](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/history).

Note the differences between the Google appengine Q/As. The answer heading is also slightly smaller, which doesn't seem to occur on the normal Edit Review screen.

> [image]